# In-App purchase non renewable subscription limit to 5 devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

We have implemented In-App purchase non renewable subscription. We would like to limit the app to 5 devices with the given login. Suppose a account is created with the app and buy subscription this account is being logged in 5 different devices and accessing the feature to share PDF file to DropBox and if same account trying to access the 6th device and access the feature to share PDF will be disabled and will say "device limit is reached" and will be give option to remove previously added device in order to get access to share the PDF file.

Apple documentation says your app In-App purchase should work on all devices. We are letting new device to use the app by disabling the previously added device.

Is this logic of device enable/disable acceptable by apple?
Any advise will appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Not at all. Apple is very clear about this: "work on all devices".